# Could not work with input type password in mozilla

Tags: php, html, css, cookies

I have using input type password.but click a box hide add text pointer.How to solve? Following my code.

```html
  <div class=" form-group has-error">
                       <label><i class="im im-icon-Lock-2"></i>Password: </label>   
                       <input type="password"   id="log_txt_password"   class="effect-16" name="log_txt_password" value="<?php echo $this->input->cookie('ctracker_password'); ?>" >
                      
                       <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('txt_password'); ?></span>
                       <span class="focus-border"></span>
                    </div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password

Comment: sorry ,check my code now.

Comment: I think it is cookie issue.please help anyone.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question and your problem, it's not very clear what you are looking. Thanks.